# How to retrieve size of each attachment of mail using openpop .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openpop

I use openpop .net library to retrieve mails from mail server with POP3. All works fine but I can't retrieve size of each attachment of mail. I founded GetMessageSize(i) but this size is sum of all attachments.

Then the question is how I can retrieve size of each attachment.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`attachment.Body`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.Body.html).

```
foreach(var attachment in message.FindAllAttachments())
{
    long byteSize = attachment.Body.Length;
}
```